# How can I store confidential S3 information for my dev env that is shared with production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, heroku, amazon-s3

My dev bucket uses the same credentials as my production bucket.

Since I am using Heroku, I have moved all these credentials into my Heroku Config. Which would work except for my development env since its on my local.

How can I store this information securely so that this data is not being seen on a public repo but is still accessible and instantiated to my local machine?

Comment: can't you just set your credentials as environment variables in a shell script (eg. env.sh) and then gitignore that? Then just ``source env.sh`` on your local machine and you should be set

Answer (score 1):

Rails 4.1 can do this internally, but until then you might find these helpful:

- https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv
- https://github.com/jcamenisch/ENV_BANG/

For info on 4.1, see the 'secrets.yml' section.

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html

update: Appears I was mistaken about Rails 4.1.  While it has a secrets.yml file it's not encrypted.  Wonder where I read that it was...

Comment: I don't get the `secrets.yml` feature. It's still stored in your repo, and if it's public, everybody will see it.

Comment: Couldn't you add `secrets.yml` to your .gitignore though?

Comment: @Trip Yes, you could.